# HTML5 include text file

Tags: html, text, include

is it possible to have large chunks of text stored in .txt files, then included in the `<p></p>` tags at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using server-side code.

Comment: Ah, I remember the time, when XHTML and XInclude had a bright, promising future. I'm getting old...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with HTML alone, you'd have to use a server side language like PHP and do a [basic include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), or potentially you could use javascript to fetch the content with Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Use server side language like PHP, ASP, JSP, and the like. You can use the language's features like include to include the text file.

If you don't want to use server side language, you can use ajax:

```
$.post("testfile.txt", "", function(response) {
    $('p').text(response); /* display text file content */
});
```